# Refreshing data from server using NSTimer

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, nstimer

i want to refresh the data from the server ,but that refreshing time-> i want to get that from the user and pass to the timer ,how can i do this i know to give the value like,

```
self.timerCounter =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:300.0  
target:self selector:@selector(getGraphData) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

i also tried using protocols and delegates like ,

```
self.timerCounter =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:strTime
target:self selector:@selector(getGraphData) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

but i got error like

> Sending NSString _strong to parameter of incompatible type
>   NSTimerInterval

now ,i want to get that from the user in the textfield ,please help me to do this

Comment: Can you post how your are assigning value to `strTime`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is the problem in converting `strTime` to NSTimeInterval.

```
self.timerCounter =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[strTime doubleValue] target:self selector:@selector(getGraphData) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Try this, This should work if there is conversion problem..

Answer (score 1):

Convert `textfield.text` to `NSTimeInterval` 
Try like,
`let strTime : NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval(textfield.text)!`

Comment: I just get the values from the nsuserdefaults ,like, NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *url = [defaults objectForKey:@"server_url"];
    NSString *txtTime =[defaults objectForKey:@"refresh_time"];   
   self.timerCounter =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:txtTime target:self selector:@selector(getGraphData) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

Comment: Objective-C syntax is NSTimeInterval time = [txtTime doubleValue];

Answer (score 1):

You are using `NSString` instead of a `NSTimeInterval` type data. You should be able to resolve this by converting your `txtTime` or `strTime` to a double value.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *url = [defaults objectForKey:@"server_url"];
NSString *txtTime = [defaults objectForKey:@"refresh_time"];

if (txtTime != nil) {
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [txtTime doubleValue];
    self.timerCounter = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeInterval target:self selector:@selector(getGraphData) userInfo:nil repeats:true];
}
```